# In this sentence, what is "something"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

We expect people to monitor machines, which means keeping alert for long periods, something we are bad at.

1. something is "monitor machines" or "machines"
2. something is "which means keeping alert for long periods"

Comment: "Something" is whatever follows "which means". I expect Mary to win hearts, which means dancing the polka, something she is good at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**something** is pronoun: it stands in for a noun or a noun phrase. Neither of the options that you have proposed is a noun phrase.

"to monitor machines" starts with a to-infinitive, so it is a noun phrase.

"keeping alert for long periods" starts with a gerund, so it is a noun phrase.

Replace **something** with each of these noun phrases and see which makes the better, and more sensible, sentence. My money is on this one:

> We are bad at keeping alert for long periods.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You explained a noun and noun phrase. What about a noun clause for "something"?

Comment: mmm you could do, but there are few situations where it would make a nice sentence. Here is an example "that so many people voted for X is something that is hard to understand", and it would be better written as ""that so many people voted for X is hard to understand"